# `echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile`, what each part of the command actually mean/does?

Tags: java, macos, terminal

To set JAVA_HOME on mac, one simply have to type `echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile` in terminal.

However, I was just wondering if anyone could explain what each part of the command actually mean/does?

Comment: I'm fairly certain most of this has been covered *ad nauseam*. I find it hard to believe you are having trouble with `echo`, `export` and shell redirection. A modicom of effort should have told you what they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile` is a private, i.e. for a particular user, startup file for bash shell. In other words, when you open a shell (command line), the shell program reads this file to know what should be executed to [initialize the shell environment](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html).

`JAVA_HOME` is an environment variable used by various programs to find Java binaries and other Java-related files. You can set the variable by just executing `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` in the command line, but it will be effective only during that shell session.

So, in order for the `JAVA_HOME` variable to persist between sessions, you set it automatically in `~/.bash_profile` by appending the `export` command to this file using `echo` and redirection. `echo` prints a message, `>>` redirects the output, in this case into the `~/.bash_profile` file. Notice the double-greater-than sign (`>>`) -- it means ***append***, as opposed to `>`, which means ***overwrite***.

In order to treat the argument of the `echo` command "as is" without interpreting it, the argument is enclosed in double-quotes and the dollar sign is escaped (i.e. `\$`).

To sum up, you should see the following line at the bottom of your `~/.bash_profile` file after executing the command (run `cat ~/.bash_profile` to view the file's contents):

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

And `$(command)` syntax is used for [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), that is `/usr/libexec/java_home` will be executed and its output assigned to `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: thank you so much for the awesome explanation! I was just wondering where I could find information regarding to all those symbols and command? some time commands can get very complex and confusing :(